# Adding marker to google map from AsyncTask

Tags: google-maps, android-asynctask

I am having a very strange problem which it is making me crazy. I add marker to my map from AsyncTask to avoid blocking the main thread. In Nexus 4 with 4.2.2 it is working fine but in tablet galaxy with 3.2 or galaxy ace with 2.3.7 it is giving me a null pointer exception when do map.addMarker(). The error is for the MarkerOption becuause if I create a MarkerOption in the OnProgrssUpdate is not having the error. I check that the object is not null and it is not. Even I put a log.d before the addMarker and the object is correct however I got the error. Here you have the code:

```
    private class MapItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Item, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... values) {
            int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
            for (int companyId : companies) {
                try {
                    Company company = DBCompanies.getCompany(db_path,
                            GSSettings.DBCODE, companyId);
                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(company.getLatitude(),
                            company.getLongitude());
                    if (pos.latitude == 0 && pos.longitude == 0)
                        continue;

                    Subcategory subcategory = DBParameters.getSubcategory(
                            db_path, GSSettings.DBCODE, company
                                    .getSubcategoriesId()[0], Locale
                                    .getDefault().getLanguage());


    Bitmap bitmap;
                    if (subcategory.getMarker() != null
                            && subcategory.getMarker().length > 1)
                        bitmap = GSTools.getBitmapFromMDPI(
                                subcategory.getMarker(), density);
                    else
                        bitmap = GSTools.getBitmapFromMDPI(
                                subcategory0.getMarker(), density);

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(pos).anchor(0, 1)
                            .title(company.getName())
                            .snippet(subcategory.getName())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
            Item item = new Item(markerOptions, company.getId());

            publishProgress(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Item... values) {
        try {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = values[0].markerOptions;
            Log.d("marker", markerOptions.getTitle());


    //              markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
    //                      .position(new LatLng(37.750087, -0.848522))
    //                      .anchor(0, 1)
    //                      .title("TT")
    //                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    //                              .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_button_map));
            Marker m = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            haspMap.put(m, values[0].comapnyId);
            Log.d("marker", markerOptions.getTitle());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("marker", e.toString());
        }

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    }
```

If I use the MarkerOption commented works. Any idea????

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
 public void run()
 {
    // add your marker here
    Marker m = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    haspMap.put(m, company.getId());
    Log.d("marker", markerOptions.getTitle());

 }
});
```

instead of using the progress update mechanism for updating your UI.  mContext is your activity/context

Comment: It is giving me the same error. With runOnUiThread in android 4.2.2 works fine but not in 3.2 or 2.3.7.?????it is crazy. The MarkerOptions is created correctly but when I run map.addMarker(markerOptions) nullpointerexception.....

Comment: runOnUiThread doesn't block the main thread, nor does it stop the background thread from continuing.  Run in a debugger to find out which value is null

Comment: suggest breaking down your new MarkerOptions().position().title().snippet() into separate steps, see where null is coming from

Comment: I am very sorry for this. The error was that this function, GSTools.getBitmapFromMDPI(subcategory.getMarker(), density);
to adapt resolution it was returning null for other than xhdp. The object markerOptions was not null but the icon was null and the result fom the exception was not clear. Sorry and many thanks for your help CSmith. This made me to waste 4 hours.